# allow only letters, numbers, and spaces. replace repeated spaces with single space

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m replacing weird characters with `""` but I have two scenarios that are not covered.

strings can contain multiple spaces (only one should be allowed) and underscore `(       , _)`

```
"this_is_my_string".replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "");
```

how to tweak it to cover those scenarios?

examples

```
this_is_my_string => thisismystring
this is my string => this is my string
this     is     my string => this is my string
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output.  From what I can see, you may need multiple replacements here.

Comment: absolutely. done!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = [
  'this_is_my_string',
  'this is my string',
  'this     is     my string',
  'this%$is my@@@string',
];
console.log(test.map(function(a) {
  return a.replace(/(\s)+|[\W_]/g, "$1");
}));
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/QUEcux/1)

Comment: (You can also repeat the `[\W_]+` :-) )

Comment: one space is allowed but this one is not letting me add one :(

Comment: @handsome: Sorry, I don't get you. Where do you want to add extra space? This regex acts exactly as you describe in your question. It removes special characters and replaces any number of spaces with just one. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is this regex:

```
    value.replace(/_|[^\w\s*]|\s{1,}/g,"");
```

The `_|` any character that matches `_` [OR] `[^` (Negated nest): will match any character that not in the set which is: `\w\s*` word, whitespace, 0 or more instances of the preceding regex token. `]|` exiting the negated nest. [OR] `\s{2}` , 2 white spaces

Comment: Sure!,
The `_|` any character  that matches `_` [OR]
`[^` (Negated nest): will match any character that not in the set which is:
`\w\s*` word, whitespace, 0 or more instances of the preceding regex token.
`]|` exiting the negated nest. [OR]
`\s{2}` , 2 white spaces @showdev

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_k1998/Lse6z7kn/9/) for it

Comment: Note that the outcome for all the examples is `thisismystring` which does not seem correct for the second and third example string.

Comment: The [original version](https://jsfiddle.net/6s49wm2p/) seems to work better.

Answer (score -1):

you could try being more specific with the words part and instead match on the characters, the for the spacing you could just look for more than one space.

```
[^A-Za-z\s]|\s{2,}
```

Comment: Not my DV but how will you differentiate between replacing with an empty string or a space?

Comment: They added the test cases after I answered, my assumption originally is this was going to be used in input validation (like as the user types in.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this regex:

`/[ \t]{2,}|[\_]/`

It will select two or more spaces and underscores.

Comment: Not my DV but how will you differentiate between replacing with an empty string or a space?